# Rest-assured is adding "NORMAL_OUTPUT" to the end of log lines

Tags: java, intellij-idea, output

I'm testing some API with restassured. My call to restassured looks (more-or less) like this:

```
public void doRequest() {
    XMLRequestBindingClass body = new XMLBindingClass(/*some paramenters*/);
    RequestSpecification request = given()
                .config(getDefaultConfig())
                .contentType(ContentType.XML)
                .header(AUTH_HEADER) // "SOAPAction","http://some.soap.action"
                .header(ACTION_HEADER) // "Authorization", "s0meHash"
                .body(body, ObjectMapperType.JAXB);
    XMLResponseBindingClass response = getServiceResponse(request, URL, timeout)
                .as(XMLResponseBindingClass.class);
}

protected Response getServiceResponse(RequestSpecification request, String url, long timeout) {
    if (isDebugEnabled) {
        request.log().all();
    }
    Response response = request.when().post(url);
    if (isDebugEnabled) {
        response.prettyPeek();
    }
    ValidatableResponse validatableResponse = response
            .then().statusCode(200);
    if (checkTime && timeout != 0) {
        validatableResponse.time(lessThanOrEqualTo(timeout));
    }
    return validatableResponse.extract().response();
}

protected static RestAssuredConfig getDefaultConfig() {
    RestAssuredConfig config = RestAssuredConfig
            .config()
            .sslConfig(SSLConfig.sslConfig().relaxedHTTPSValidation())
            .encoderConfig(EncoderConfig.encoderConfig().defaultContentCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
            .logConfig(LogConfig.logConfig()
                                .enablePrettyPrinting(true))
            .xmlConfig(XmlConfig.xmlConfig()
                                .with().namespaceAware(true)
                                .with().allowDocTypeDeclaration(true));
    if (!isDebugEnabled) {
        /* Request and response will be printed in case restassured built-in validation fails
           (e.g. .then.status(200) failing if service returned 404 instead of 200)
           for other failures (e.g. field having wrong value), assertion-functions logging abilities should be used. */
        config.getLogConfig().enableLoggingOfRequestAndResponseIfValidationFails(LogDetail.ALL);
    }
    return config;
}
```

LogLevel is set to DEBUG on my machine, so I get all the details of request and response.

This all worked fine until recently (though I haven't changed anything around the request). But now some requests and responses (no obvious pattern) are getting logged like this (data obfuscated):

```
Request method: POSTNORMAL_OUTPUT
Request URI:    http://some.url/hereNORMAL_OUTPUT
Proxy:          <none>NORMAL_OUTPUT
Request params: <none>NORMAL_OUTPUT
Query params:   <none>NORMAL_OUTPUT
Form params:    <none>NORMAL_OUTPUT
Path params:    <none>NORMAL_OUTPUT
Multiparts:     <none>NORMAL_OUTPUT
Headers:        SOAPAction=http://some.soap.actionNORMAL_OUTPUT
            Accept=text/xmlNORMAL_OUTPUT
            Content-Type=application/xml; charset=UTF-8NORMAL_OUTPUT

Cookies:        <none>NORMAL_OUTPUT
Body:NORMAL_OUTPUT
<ns3:Envelope xmlns:ns6="http://..." xmlns:ns5="http://..." xmlns:ns2="http://..." xmlns:ns4="http://..." xmlns:ns3="http://...">NORMAL_OUTPUT
  <ns3:Body>NORMAL_OUTPUT
    <ns6:wrapperTag>NORMAL_OUTPUT
      <ns5:Header/>NORMAL_OUTPUT
      <ns5:SearchCriteria>NORMAL_OUTPUT
        <ns5:FirstName>Jane</ns5:FirstName>NORMAL_OUTPUT
        <ns5:LastName>Doe</ns5:LastName>NORMAL_OUTPUT
      </ns5:SearchCriteria>NORMAL_OUTPUT
    </ns6:wrapperTag>NORMAL_OUTPUT
  </ns3:Body>NORMAL_OUTPUT
</ns3:Envelope>NORMAL_OUTPUT
HTTP/1.1 200 OKNORMAL_OUTPUT
Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2016 13:43:03 GMTNORMAL_OUTPUT
Server: Oracle-HTTP-Server-12cNORMAL_OUTPUT
Content-Length: 4519NORMAL_OUTPUT
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: ssome^hashhhh_12^s000000meth11111ngDNORMAL_OUTPUT
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2NORMAL_OUTPUT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100NORMAL_OUTPUT
Connection: Keep-AliveNORMAL_OUTPUT
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8NORMAL_OUTPUT
Content-Language: enNORMAL_OUTPUT
NORMAL_OUTPUT
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">NORMAL_OUTPUT
  <Body xmlns:ns2="http://epicor.com/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">NORMAL_OUTPUT
    <wrapperTag xmlns="http://epicor.com/">NORMAL_OUTPUT
        <PERSON>NORMAL_OUTPUT
          <ID>123</ID>NORMAL_OUTPUT
          <LST_NM>DOE</LST_NM>NORMAL_OUTPUT
          <FRST_NM>JANE</FRST_NM>NORMAL_OUTPUT
          <ADDR_LN_1>123 BLABLA STREET</ADDR_LN_1>NORMAL_OUTPUT
          <ADDR_CITY>BLABLA</ADDR_CITY>NORMAL_OUTPUT
          <ADDR_ST>CA</ADDR_ST>NORMAL_OUTPUT
          <ADDR_CTRY>US</ADDR_CTRY>NORMAL_OUTPUT
          <ADDR_ZIP>12345</ADDR_ZIP>NORMAL_OUTPUT
          <EMAIL>JANE.DOE@SOME.MAIL</EMAIL>NORMAL_OUTPUT
        </PERSON>NORMAL_OUTPUT
        <!-- more PERSON here, all with these "NORMAL_OUTPUT"-->
        <!-- And at the end of response, all of a sudden-->
        <PERSON>NORMAL_OUTPUT
          <ID>345</ID>NORMAL_OUTPUT
          <LST_NM>DOE</LST_NM>
          <FRST_NM>JANE</FRST_NM>
          <ADDR_LN_1>345 BLABLA ST APT 789</CUST_ADDR_LN_1>
          <ADDR_CITY>BLABLA</CUST_ADDR_CITY>
          <ADDR_ST>CA</CUST_ADDR_ST>
          <ADDR_CTRY>US</CUST_ADDR_CTRY>
          <ADDR_ZIP>12345</CUST_ADDR_ZIP>
          <EMAIL>JANE.DOE@OTHER.MAIL</CUST_ADDR_EMAIL>
        </PERSON>
        <!-- one more PERSON, totally normal-->
      </wrapperTag>
    </Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Does anybody know where could this "NORMAL_OUTPUT" come from?

I've tried to debug to find out where does it come from, but while I was debugging, all was OK, though when the test finished, I found it all over the log again. I use IntelliJ, TestNG, Restassure 3.0.0 (also tried to switch to 3.0.1 and all wass the same). I run my tests via IntelliJ TestNG run. And except from this weird output everything works as expected.

UPD: I found out that it is IntelliJ Idea adding "NORMAL_OUTPUT" to the end of each line. But I couldn't yet find anything else about conditions making it do that. Any ideas?